# CodeIgniter: distributed production deployment

Tags: codeigniter, distributed, deployment

Couldn't find any references on how to deploy a CodeIgniter application distributedly: One (or many, through a load balancer) machine to views + controllers; samething for the Model layer.

Does codeigniter offer a easy setup on this, or will I have to set this up on my own?

Any thoughts appreciated :)

Comment: should this really be handled by the CodeIgniter framework and not the http server in between?

Comment: You're right on the deploy part, but not on the communication... Communication between layers is an issue to be handled by codeigniter, IMO. I can easily, for example, setup a Spring (I'm not saying codeigniter is the same as spring, just giving an example for the sake of the argument) layer to communicate to another through SOAP.

Comment: CI is a pretty basic framework. I don't think you'll find anything that advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP load balancer should handle which server running your codeigniter application should serve the incoming request. All your views, models and controllers will be replicated across all servers, but will communicate with one single data store (eg: mysql db). A unique session between the client and your server will maintain synchronicity between which server instance the client is being served from.

I don't think you really need to worry about creating a soap layer, unless each of your application servers are maintaining their own Databases locally, and then synchronizing to a master DB or among themselves.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you... you're suggesting I develop all the application in one box, then I change all the method calls to http requests to the same (or another) server, giving the load balancer the ability to decide which layer to call?

Comment: I think there is a disconnect here in our understanding of how internally the applications calls to the model/views from the controller. Why would you make HTTP calls to your methods ?? CodeIgniter will take care of making those requests internally.

Comment: That's it: I don't want the calls to be internal. I want to be able to detach the business logic from the views, physically.

Comment: I don't see how that can help you in building a scalable app using CodeIgniter. But if that's what you want, then CodeIgniter is probably not the right framework for you. Also, do keep in mind that in CodeIgniter, your business logic is still separated from your views, though not physically. It'd be great if you could provide some insights into how separating the views physically impacts deploying on a distributed environment.